# How can i save the data in sql from the cell after editing in jTable(autosave)?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, autosave

i have populated Jtable, but now i want to update sql record if i change a cell's value then it should change in sql databases automatically.

Comment: >You will need a method for executing an update on your database where you pass your values. And an action listener binded to your JTable cells you just awnsered your owne Question congratz 

>>i want to update sql WHEN >> if i change a cell's value

Answer (score 2):

> i want to update sql record if i change a cell's value then it should change in sql databases automatically

There is no such thing as autosave (in the base JDK classes). So you will need to write code to listen for changes to the data in the table and then update your database manully using SQL.

For this you can add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel` of your `JTable`. Then when the event fires you get the data from the TableModel and update your database.

Note the `TableModelListener` will generate an event if you start to edit the cell and just tab out of the cell even if you don't change the data. So you may want to consider using the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) which will only generate an event if the data in the cell is actually changed.